# Azure Functions Consumption plan failover

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-functions, serverless

If you're using Consumption plan for Azure Functions is there any kind of failover if your region goes down or hardware failure occurs? Hardware failure I'd assume yes, but for a region it doesn't seem like it since you can only choose one.

So if we really need multi-region failover are we limited to using App Service plan for Functions?

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe one option could be to deploy multiple instances of the same Function using consumption plan to different regions and then control flow using APIM or Traffic Manager?

Comment: Interesting question, I guess Microsoft is managing the plateform and it should automatically switch to another region/datacenter

Comment: It won't failover to another region. Most trigger types are bound to region too. What is your trigger?

Comment: @Mikhail - Yea, that's what I figured. Wasn't thinking about a specific trigger type. Just speaking in general. But is there some official docs about what you're talking about with certain trigger types being bound by region?

Comment: For Function Apps running on App Service Plans we guarantee that the associated Functions compute will be available 99.95% of the time.
No SLA is provided for Functions Apps running under Consumption Plans.

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/functions/v1_0/
Probably not a good idea to do any mission critical stuff using Consumption plan Azure Functions.

Comment: @JoeyEng The SLA has been updated for consumption plan to %99.95

Comment: @kay.one wow, that's great news!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't failover to a different geo region, no matter the hosting SKU. Use [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) to achieve that level of redundancy.

Needless to say, all resources your function depends on need to exist in the 2nd region as well (SQL instances, Redis, Event Hubs, ...). You are responsible for keeping state consistent across regions (think [Azure SQL auto-failover groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview#auto-failover-group-capabilities)).

One notable exception is Cosmos DB, which (if [configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/distribute-data-globally)) can have automagically-managed replicas in multiple regions. Your function will always use the same connection string.